# How to increase chances of certain words to be selected as keywords in Rake-Nltp

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, keyword

I'm using Rake-Nltp to generate keywords from sentences. I want to increase preferences for some words to be selected as keywords. My dataset is based on football(soccer) commentary... so for eg
Sentence: Player1 puts a cross from right wing.. here 'cross' should be a keyword with high score in my usecase but Rake-Nltp gives a lower score for it.

I tried implementing a custom score function but it does not seem to work

PS: I know the code is not for my specific use case.. but this code has no change on the result whatsoever.

```
def custom_scoring_function(word_frequency, word_degree, degree_to_frequency_ratio):
    # Increase score for words that match a certain pattern
    scores = {}
    # Loop through all candidate keywords
    for word in word_frequency.keys():
        # Example custom rule: give higher scores to keywords with more than one word
        if len(word.split()) > 1:
            scores[word] = word_degree[word] * 10
        else:
            scores[word] = (word_degree[word] / degree_to_frequency_ratio[word]) * 3
    return scores
```

```
r = Rake(ranking_metric=custom_scoring_function, stopwords=stopwords, max_length=3)
```